# call a plugin from javascript crm?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

i need to pass some values from JavaScript  to Plugin.

and need to retrieve resultant result from plugin should get invoke in the java script.

can anybody guide how to proceed with this approach.

- please send some sample code & Link , how to invoke plugin from  java script and pass parameter.
- How to get the resultant from plugin to   java script.
- My plugin fires in retrieve multiple and ill get a collection of records. based on the plugin result , i need to use the result in my java script.

If i am not still clear , please find the bellow link what exactly my requirement .,

Can you please guide me how to proceed on this.

Thanks

Comment: any ideas   ... 
any other approach

Answer (score 0):

You can't call a plugin from javascript.
But, you can retrieve records from CRM, for example with ODATA. On the Retrieve / RetrieveMultiple event of the entity, you can register a plugin with some custom code. Place the result of the plugin in a field of the entity. Then read the result from the entity which you retrieved by ODATA. You can create a custom entity for this Plugin Messaging Mechanism.